# ¿Cómo evitar "Error de lectura XML: no se encuentra elemento" sin reiniciar tomcat?

Tags: web, hibernate, tomcat

Tengo un proyecto web que utiliza hibernate y está desplegado con tomcat en la máquina virtual de un servidor. En principio puedo acceder a la página donde pide los datos de identificación, pero al hacer login me da el siguiente error:

```
Error de lectura XML: no se encuentra elemento
Ubicación: http://ip/proyecto/login.xhtml
Número de línea 1, columna 1:
```

Tanto apache, como tomcat, como mysql están activos. Pero si reseteo apache con el comando "sudo systemctl restar tomcat", puedo hacer login con normalidad y de login.xhtml accedo a paciente.xhtml. Sin embargo, pasado un tiempo sin actividad en la página (desconozco cuánto), vuelve a aparecer el mismo error.

He aumentado el tiempo de expiración de sesiones de tomcat, pero no parece ser el problema. ¿Cómo podría evitar este error sin tener que reiniciar tomcat cada vez?

No hay comentarios, espacios ni saltos de línea en el primer elemento de ningún xml. En principio, al hacer login cargaría "hibernate.cfg.xml", pero no parece que haya problemas. Aquí el archivo:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name</property>
        <property name="connection.username">user</property>
        <property name="connection.password">password</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <mapping class="proyecto.Paciente" />
        ...

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```